# C++ program only lists last value entered into an array

Tags: c++, arrays

I am trying to output the values present in the array, that are accepted during runtime, onto the console. But when I run this program I get the 5 values in the array as the last value only.

For example: if i give `0 1 2 3 4` as the five values for this program then the output is shown as   `4 4 4 4 4`.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int arrsize = 5;
  int *ptr = new int[arrsize];

  *ptr = 7;

  cout << *ptr << endl;
  cout << "enter 5 values:";

  for (int i = 0; i < arrsize; i++)
  {
    cin >> *ptr;

    cin.get();
  }

  cout << "the values in the array are:\n ";

  for (int i = 0; i < arrsize; i++)
  {
    cout << *ptr << " ";
  }

  delete[] ptr;
  cin.get();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You never seem to increment/offset `ptr` within the input or output loop.

Comment: And if you're going to program in C++, why not take advantage of the STL? Declare a `vector` of `int`s and `push_back` elements into it in your input loop. No need to `new` anything.

Comment: To elaborate on what @Michael said, `ptr` *always* points to the first element of the array, so `*ptr` is *always* the same as writing `ptr[0]`. You're reading into the first element of the array five times, then writing the first element out five times.  In both loops, consider using `ptr[i]` instead of `*ptr`.

Comment: Yeah :) it's done.   thanks both of you . it was simple program that i had done in c also, but slightly got confused with that dynamic memory allocation . Thanks once again

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Following issues I think you could tackle:

- The first `include` can be omitted I think. Your code works without that.
- You use `cin.get()`, not sure why you need that. I think you can remove that. Even the one at the very end. You could put a `cout << endl` for the last newline. I am using Linux.
- And use `ptr` like an array with index: `ptr[i]` in the loops as mentioned in the other answer. `ptr[i]` is equivalent to `*(ptr+i)`. You have to offset it, otherwise you're overwriting the same value (that is why you get that result), because `ptr` points to the first element of the array.

P.S.: It seems that if you're using Windows (or other systems) you need the   `cin.get()` to avoid the console to close down or so. So maybe you'd need to check it. See comments below.

Comment: `cin.get()` is usually used on Windows platform to prevent the terminal from closing the console window at program termination. The first `include` is also fairly common among students.

Comment: Not sure why your answer was downvoted though. It looks fine to me.

Comment: Not sure if that's worth a downvote. For that program the user didn't need the first include. Also not sure if cin.get() is a good practice. I assume you're just voting strategically.

Comment: @Elyasin if this is Visual Studio, then yes, they *really* need that first include *or* need to change a lot of compiler settings (precompiled header settings)

Comment: thanks Elyasin i'm new to stackoverflow . so i made a mistake . and your answer was useful. sorry for that

Comment: (About the final `cin.get()`) It's not really a Windows-only issue. It's trick to force a program to keep running even after it has finished all the important work. The same thing would be required in Linux if running such a program directly inside an X terminal (i.e. with no shell in between)

Comment: Hmmm, I never encountered that. Is that very common? What do you mean with X Terminal without shell?

Answer (score 1):

Both of your loops:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrsize; i++)
    ...
```

loop over a variable `i` that is never used inside the loop. You are always using `*ptr` which refers always to the first element of the dynamically allocated array. You should use `ptr[i]` instead.

---

A part from that, dynamic allocation is an advanced topic. I'd recommend sticking with simpler and more commonly used things first:

```
std::cout << "Enter values:";
std::vector<int> array(std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin), {});
std::cout << "\nThe values in the array are:\n";
std::copy(begin(array), end(array), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b55f8cf07a61f442)